# is tokenizer a must have in a parser?

Tags: parsing, compilation

A tokenizer, lexer, and parser usually come together as 3 standard parts.

- Can a parser be made without a tokenizer and the AST be built directly from the input? What are the benefits and drawbacks that tokenizing brings?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the tokenizer, sure, but then backtracking and lookahead become more complicated because you need to re-scan everything character by character. That makes your parser much harder to maintain and modify, and also just a bit slower.